# How to directly Pass Gridview row cell value in UID and Article without using textbox

Tags: asp.net

```
if (IsPostBack)
{
    GridViewRow grdrow = (GridViewRow)((LinkButton)sender).NamingContainer;

    //Iframe1.Attributes.Add("src", "Drawing.aspx?UID=" + grdrow.Cells[0].Text + "&Article=" + grdrow.Cells[1].Text + "&testdrawing= kkk");
    //Iframe1.Attributes.Add("src", "Drawing2.aspx?UID=" + grdrow.Cells[0].Text + "&Article=" + grdrow.Cells[1].Text);
    //Iframe1.Attributes.Add("src", "Drawing2.aspx?UID=" + TextBox1.Text + "&Article=" + TextBox2.Text);
    Iframe1.Attributes.Add("src", "Drawing2.aspx?UID=" + TextBox1.Text + "&Article=" + TextBox2.Text + "&testdrawing= kkk");
    //Iframe1.Attributes.Add("src", "Drawing2.aspx?UID=" + grdrow.Cells[0].Text + "&Article=" + grdrow.Cells[1].Text) + "&testdrawing= kkk");
    TextBox1.Text = grdrow.Cells[0].Text;
    TextBox2.Text = grdrow.Cells[1].Text;
    //GridViewRow row = GridView1.SelectedRow;
    //TextBox1.Text = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[0].Text;
    //TextBox2.Text = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I feel like I am misunderstanding the question but if I understand your question correctly just replace:

```
Iframe1.Attributes.Add("src", "Drawing2.aspx?UID=" + TextBox1.Text + "&Article=" + TextBox2.Text + "&testdrawing= kkk");
```

with

```
Iframe1.Attributes.Add("src", "Drawing2.aspx?UID=" + grdrow.Cells[0].Text + "&Article=" + grdrow.Cells[1].Text + "&testdrawing= kkk");
```

Comment: Depends on what he is asking, why I mentioned possibly not understanding the question

Comment: No problem, if this answered your question please mark my answer as the correct one.